# titlesec: display subsectiontitle in header only if there is a subsection

Tags: conditionals, titlesec

I want to have my header as the section name displayed on the left and the subsection name displayed on the right. This works well as long as every section has a subsection. However if there is no subsection in a section, it keeps listing the last subsection from an previous section.

How can I change my code to have only a subsection displayed if there actually is a new subsection in the current section?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pagestyles,extramarks]{titlesec}
\settitlemarks*{section,subsection}
\newpagestyle{mypage}[\small]{%
  \sethead{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle}%
  {}%
  {\firstextramarks{subsection}\thesubsection.~\subsectiontitle}%
  \setfoot{}%
  {\thepage}%
  {}%
}
\pagestyle{mypage}


\begin{document}
\section{First section}
This section should not have a subsection in the header.
\newpage
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Test}
This section should have a subsection in the header.
\newpage
\section{Third section}
This section should not have a subsection in the header.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `titlesec` package defines conditionals `\ifthechapter, \ifthesection, ...` which do the job:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pagestyles,extramarks]{titlesec}
\settitlemarks*{section,subsection}
\newpagestyle{mypage}[\small]{%
  \sethead{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle}%
  {}%
  {\ifthesubsection{\firstextramarks{subsection}\thesubsection.~\subsectiontitle}{}}%
  \setfoot{}%
  {\thepage}%
  {}%
}
\pagestyle{mypage}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
This section should not have a subsection in the header.
\newpage
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Test}
This section should have a subsection in the header.
\newpage
\section{Third section}
This section does not have a subsection in the header.

\end{document}
```

[image]